# MaterialCalendarView: How to get CalendarDay value on decorate method?

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using MaterialCalendarView (https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) in my app., My objective to create price view (as attached in picture). I have a map which contains selected date & their price.

Please help me to understand how can I get CalendarDay value at decorate method so that I can get price value from map.

```
 public class DaysDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {
 private final Context context;
 Map<CalendarDay, String> priceMap;

public DaysDecorator(Context context, Map<CalendarDay, String> priceMap){
    this.context = context;
    this.priceMap = priceMap;
}
@Override
public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
    return priceMap.containsKey(day);
}

 @Override
 public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
```

> //How to get CalendarDay here

```
    int price = priceMap.get();

    view.addSpan(new PriceSpan(35, Color.LTGRAY, 120000));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you have misunderstood one of the principles behind DayViewDecorator.

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to set a specific value for the PriceSpan (i.e. the small text/value shown below the date) for each day. This cannot be achieved with a single `DayViewDecorator`. A `DayViewDecorator` applies one specific style/drawing/whatever (defined through the `decorate()`-method) for all days that are in the set of applicable dates (In your case `priceMap`).

In other words, what happens in `decorate()`, happens for all those days which resulted in `true` from a previous call to `shouldDecorate()`.

I'm afraid that you are going to have to use specific decorators for each unique value in your Map.

Comment: Yes, I changed the logic. I added decorator for every day where price are available. may be its not perfect solution but it works.

Comment: How do you build a PriceSpan class. Just I can not set the size to text and set text to center|bottom. Thank you.